# How to communicate from the back end to the front end in a MEAN stack application?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm new to the MEAN stack app and am having some trouble trying to send data from the server to the front end. However, I do have some communication going on, but this is all I can seem to do. In the server I have the json message being sent.

## Server

```
router.route("/users/register").post((req, res) => { 

registerLogin.findOne({ $or: [{ username }, { email }]}, (err, user) => {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        else if (!username || !email || !password)  
            res.status(403).json({ registerErrRequired: "Fill out whole form." });
```

## Front end

```
 registerUser(username, email, password)  {
    const user =  {
      username: username,
      email: email,
      password: password
    };
    return this.http.post(`${this.uri}/users/register`, user)
    .pipe(map(response => console.log(response)))

    .subscribe(() => { this.router.navigate(["/users/login"]) }, (errResp) => {

      errResp.error ? this.ngFlashMessageService.showFlashMessage({

        messages: [errResp.error.registerErrRequired], // Where json message gets caught and shown to the browser
      dismissible: true,
      timeout: false,
      type: 'danger'
      }) : console.log("An unkown error occured.");
    });
  }
```

This works well, but I can't seem to do req/res other than using a flash message. My issue is wanting to use it in other ways than just flash messages. For example, if the user does not have a session, then I want them to navigate back to the the log in page. Here's what I tried but failed.

#### Server

```
// Middleware
const redirectLogin = ((req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.session.user) 
        res.status(401).json({ loggedIn: false });
    else
        next();
}); 
// Route
router.route("/home").get(redirectLogin, (req, res) => {
    Blog.find((err, docs) => {
        if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        res.json(docs);
    }); 
});
```

#### Front end

```
homePage() {
  // Here is where I would like to say, If session, then true, else navigate(["/users/login"])
   if (loggedIn === false)
       this.router.navigate(["/users/login"])
   else
       // Success
  return this.http.get(`${this.uri}/home`);
}
```

The only way I found communication was through sending error flash messages, but nothing else.

Comment: Just making sure i got your question right : you want to send a get request to '/home' and if user isn't logged in (session expired) you want to navigate to login page right?

Comment: @Serg you can use `socket` if you don't want to call API error message. And you can also use JWT and during the login or any route change verify jwt token expiry time if token is expired then you can redirect user to login page.

Comment: @pavan skipo that is what I am trying to do, yes, but the major issue is simply just using angular to communiate with the server.

Comment: @Yash Rami, I will have to look into sockets then, but also I don't want to use jwt, this is the reason why I chose sessions over jwt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is call an api to check whether the user is logged in or not in `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook,so every time your component loads you can check whether the session exists on backend and route accordingly.

```
 export class App implements OnInit{
          constructor(){
             //called first time before the ngOnInit()
          }

          ngOnInit(){
           //CheckLogin() is a method in your service which calls your backend api
             this.http.post("your authentication url to check if session exits ",{username:username}).subscribe(data=>{
            if (data["loggedIn"] === false)

               this.router.navigate(["/users/login"])


        }) 
          }

}
```

Angular also has `HTTP interceptors`,you can solve this issue with jwt and [http interceptors](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)

Comment: It is saying that CheckLogin does not exist on type service, also I am not using JWT. I am using sessions.

Comment: Yes because ,that method doesn't exists in your service .I thought you can improvise.Updated my answer .Pls check @Serg